'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED' error on swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens Uniswap router 02
I am building a contract to automatically swap a token with fee on transfer (I am using as a test this token t: 0x576e2BeD8F7b46D34016198911Cdf9886f78bea7) via UniswapRouter02 swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens. The recipient of the swap should be my contract as further functions have to be applied. I am using this address for UniswapRouter02 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D. I am running a local fork of Ethereum through HardHat.
In Solidity I am using this snippet:
function swapExactInputSingleHopV2(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address t) public {
     IERC20(t).transferFrom(msg.sender, myContractAddress, amountIn);
     IERC20(t).approve(routerV2, amountIn);
     address[] memory path = new address[](2);
     path[0] = t;
     path[1] = weth;
     ISwapRouter02V2(routerV2).swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(amountIn, amountOutMin, path, myContractAddress, block.timestamp);
    }


interface ISwapRouter02V2 {
    function swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
    uint amountIn,
    uint amountOutMin,
    address[] calldata path,
    address to,
    uint deadline
    ) external;
}

While through ethers.js I am approving the following:
await tContract.connect(connectedWallet).approve(myContractAddress, ethers.utils.parseUnits("10000.0", 9).toString());
await tContract.connect(connectedWallet).approve(routerV2, ethers.utils.parseUnits("10000.0", 9).toString());

When testing on Remix IDE (pragma solidity >=0.8.2 <0.9.0; using 0.8.26, default version cancun), I call swapExactInputSingleHopV2, and it works correctly only for amounts <100 of the token t, while it throws TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED for any other amount higher than 99, despite having approved way more than 10000 * 10^9.
Do you have any idea on how to solve this problem?

Your code looks ok to me. I believe the problem lies in the token, apparently it blocks some smartcontracts. Try using another token and see if it works
